# Accessing a MySQL Link Identifier from within a Function

Tags: php, function, while-loop

I'm having some difficulty returning an array out of a while lopp which I have in a function. Here is the code I am using. I am meant to be able to return an array of results from the function which contains the id numbers of pictures associated with a particular user id - in this case I want to print_r the array for the user id of 17. When this code isn't in the function it works, but when I place it in the function, no luck. I presume its related to a mistake I am making in the returning of the array. Your help is greatly appreciated.

```
function picture($id)
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM avatar WHERE user_id={$id}";
    $result = $database->query($sql);
    $results = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
       $results[] = $row;
    }
    return $results;
}
$results = picture(17);
print_r($results);
```

Comment: You need to pass your connection link `$database` into the function.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**pink box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ). You also inject variables into your query. That said, does a user ever have more than one avatar?

Comment: Try this: $sql = "SELECT * FROM avatar WHERE user_id=".$id;

Comment: @h2ooooooo - love the wording + idea behind you comment, but most of your links are broken for me.

Comment: c'mon Rikesh already gave you the solution

Comment: @Hecksa Really? They all work for me - it's a regular JS-bookmark that I've made (based on a comment/format made by someone else).

Comment: @h2ooooooo - They're working again now - was getting 404's on them. Think there might have been a brief outage, or something.

Comment: @GhostRider I've given you a solution below.

Answer (score 1):

## Your function can't access your MySQL link identifier

First of all, you're mixing object-oriented paradigm (`$database->query($sql)`) with procedural paradigm (`mysql_fetch_assoc($result)`) which will make your code a nightmare to maintain.

Assuming that `$database` is a `mysql_` link identifier, you'll need to pass it into your function in order to access it there.

```
function getUserAvatar($database, $id){
    $sql     = 'SELECT * FROM `avatar` WHERE `user_id`=' . intval($id) . ' LIMIT 1;';
    $result  = mysql_query($database, $sql);
    $row     = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

    return $row;
}

$results = picture($database, 17);
```

### Don't just copy-paste that, keep reading!

The above will probably work, but if you're allowing a user to pass that user ID into the function, it's quite possible that they'll be able to find a vulnerability to inject an SQL statement of their choice into your MySQL database.

**`mysql_` functions are deprecated, so you should ideally stop using them and switch to `mysqli` or PDO**. You'll also want to get an understanding of prepared statements in order to prevent SQL injections. If you can't upgrade, look at the `mysql_real_escape_string` and `intval` functions and make sure you sanitize all user inputs before processing them.

The resulting code will look something like this, if you switch to mysqli and [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php):

```
function getUserAvatar($db, $userId) {
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `avatar` WHERE `user_id`=? LIMIT 1;");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $userId);
    $stmt->execute();
    $res = $stmt->get_result();

    return $res->fetch_assoc();
}

$db     = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
$result = getUserAvatar($db, 17);
```

Answer (score -1):

may be you should try this..

```
function picture($id)
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM avatar WHERE user_id={$id}";
    $result = $database->query($sql);
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    return $row;
}

$results = picture(17);
print_r($results);
```

Comment: Sure. First of all you're not passing `$database` into the function, so the function has no access to the link identifier. Second, you still haven't prevented or mentioned the SQL injection vulnerability. Third, you're mixing OO and procedural programming.